# Adding an OverflowError side effect with patch - Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking, patch

I'd like to mock an `OverflowError` because I'd like to test the value of a variable is after that exception is raised. However, I do not know how to replicate an OverflowError with the libraries I am using. Libraries I am using in this specific test is `pysolar.solar` specifically the `get_altitude`, `get_azimuth` and `radiation methods`

After mindlessly trying out different numbers to try to simulate an OverflowError I decided to try out Mocking the function and introducing a side effect.

**Code I am testing** sunposition.py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pysolar.solar import get_altitude, get_azimuth, radiation as radiation_module


def sun_position(lat: float, lon: float, time: pd.Timestamp = None) -> List[float]:

    if time is None:
    time = pd.Timestamp.now(tz='UTC')

    dt = time.to_pydatetime()

    altitude = get_altitude(lat, lon, dt)
    azimuth = get_azimuth(lat, lon, dt)

    try:
        radiation = radiation_module.get_radiation_direct(dt, altitude)
    except OverflowError:
        radiation = np.nan

    return pd.Series([altitude, azimuth, radiation], index=['Alt', 'Azi', 'Rad'])
```

**What I started to do with patch **

```
"""Test sunposition module"""
import unittest
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, Mock

from bigfolder.sun import sunposition


class TestSunposition(unittest.TestCase):
"""Test functions in sunposition."""


def test_sun_position_overflow_error(self):

    error_lat = 23
    error_lon = 12
    error_time = pd.Timestamp('2007-02-18 15:13:05', tz="UTC")

    mock_args = {'side_effect': OverflowError}
    with patch('bigfolder.sun.sunposition.sun_position', **mock_args):
        # run the test

        self.assertRaises(OverflowError,  sunposition.sun_position(lat=error_lat, lon=error_lon, time=error_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I was expecting it to give me and OverFlow error... and it did, however my assertion failed anyways with an **OverflowError** My guess is that I patched at the wrong place? I don't really understand why the test failed regardless when the error was still an `OverFlow Error`

**This is what was printed out**

```
_mock_self = <MagicMock name='sun_position' id='102333856'>, args = ()
kwargs = {'lat': 23, 'lon': 12, 'time': Timestamp('2007-02-18 15:13:05+0000', tz='UTC')}
self = <MagicMock name='sun_position' id='102333856'>, _new_name = ''
_new_parent = None
_call = call(lat=23, lon=12, time=Timestamp('2007-02-18 15:13:05+0000', tz='UTC'))
seen = set(), skip_next_dot = False, do_method_calls = False
name = 'sun_position'

    def _mock_call(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs):
        self = _mock_self
        self.called = True
        self.call_count += 1
        _new_name = self._mock_new_name
        _new_parent = self._mock_new_parent

        _call = _Call((args, kwargs), two=True)
        self.call_args = _call
        self.call_args_list.append(_call)
        self.mock_calls.append(_Call(('', args, kwargs)))

        seen = set()
        skip_next_dot = _new_name == '()'
        do_method_calls = self._mock_parent is not None
        name = self._mock_name
        while _new_parent is not None:
            this_mock_call = _Call((_new_name, args, kwargs))
            if _new_parent._mock_new_name:
                dot = '.'
                if skip_next_dot:
                    dot = ''

                skip_next_dot = False
                if _new_parent._mock_new_name == '()':
                    skip_next_dot = True

                _new_name = _new_parent._mock_new_name + dot + _new_name

            if do_method_calls:
                if _new_name == name:
                    this_method_call = this_mock_call
                else:
                    this_method_call = _Call((name, args, kwargs))
                _new_parent.method_calls.append(this_method_call)

                do_method_calls = _new_parent._mock_parent is not None
                if do_method_calls:
                    name = _new_parent._mock_name + '.' + name

            _new_parent.mock_calls.append(this_mock_call)
            _new_parent = _new_parent._mock_new_parent

            # use ids here so as not to call __hash__ on the mocks
            _new_parent_id = id(_new_parent)
            if _new_parent_id in seen:
                break
            seen.add(_new_parent_id)

        ret_val = DEFAULT
        effect = self.side_effect
        if effect is not None:
            if _is_exception(effect):
>               raise effect
E               OverflowError
```

So then I thought I must have patched in the wrong place and introduced the side effect earlier than I should have? So I instead patched the method int the try block. **This was my following code.**

```
def test_sun_position_overflow_error(self):

    error_lat = 23
    error_lon = 12
    error_time = pd.Timestamp('2007-02-18 15:13:05', tz="UTC")

    mock_args = {'side_effect': OverflowError}
    with patch('bigfolder.sun.sunposition.sun_position.radiation_module.get_radiation_direct', **mock_args):
    # run the test

    self.assertRaises(OverflowError,  sunposition.sun_position(lat=error_lat, lon=error_lon, time=error_time))
```

And now my error is " `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bigfolder.sun.sunposition.sun_position'; 'bigfolder.sun.sunposition' is not a package`"

I then just changed the path to `'sun_position.radiation_module.get_radiation_direct'` but there's no module found.

So my questions are: How to replicate an OverflowError so that then I can check the value of a variable I set once that Exception is raised. Why is the first OverflowError I introduce still not pass my assertion?

Thanks

**UPDATE TEST passes**

After following @Gang 's suggestion, the `OverFlowError` was reproduced. I realized that in order to test the block for the exception, specifically that `radiation` was then `np.nan` I had to patch *the method that I wanted* to have the `OverFlowError` and not the whole method of sun_position. When I tried doing that I imported it incorrectly, as I thought the external library was part of the code. So I changed `bigfolder.sun.sunposition.sun_position.radiation_module.get_radiation_direct` to `pysolar.solar.radiation.get_radiation_direct` which is the external library that has the get_radiation_direct method I wanted to mock.

```
def test_sun_position_overflow_error(self):
    lat = 23
    lon = 12
    time = pd.Timestamp('2007-02-18 15:13:05', tz="UTC")

    # get_radiation_direct will now produce an OverFlowError(regardless of coordinates)
    mock_args = {'side_effect': OverflowError}
    # mock get_radiation_direct and produce OverFlowError
    with patch('pysolar.solar.radiation.get_radiation_direct', **mock_args):
        # Check radiation column is nan value
        assert math.isnan(sunposition.sun_position(lat=lat, lon=lon, time=time)[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the first OverflowError I introduce still not pass my assertion?

Almost there. The right way to `assertRaises`:

```
def test_sun_position_overflow_error(self):
    # This has to be here first and without func call
    with self.assertRaises(OverflowError):
        # patch the function to have an exception no matter what
        mock_args = {'side_effect': OverflowError}
        with patch('bigfolder.sun.sunposition.sun_position', **mock_args):
            # call this func to trigger an exception
            sunposition.sun_position(lat=error_lat, lon=error_lon, time=error_time)
```

After review the document, it is how to call a func inside `assertRaises`

> assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)
>
> fun(*args, **kwds) raises exc

This usage is wrong:

```
self.assertRaises(OverflowError,  sunposition.sun_position(lat=error_lat, lon=error_lon, time=error_time))
```

It should be a func name with kwargs:

```
self.assertRaises(OverflowError,  sunposition.sun_position, lat=error_lat, lon=error_lon, time=error_time)
```

Comment: Great! I was asserting it incorrectly @Gang. In regards to to where I patched, I realized this simulated an `OverFlowError` not where I wanted it to, since at the end what I really want is to check that `radiation` is `np.nan`. But first I had to make sure the the overflow error was produced. Thanks for answering my question. I'm updating the above(with the right patches) for what I wanted to test(in case it helps anyone).